# mongo db get collections starting with

Tags: mongodb

I have a number of collections by names like

```
app_users5473275725743
app_users5473275725746
app_users5473275725747
app_users5473275725748
```

I want to be able to find all the collections starting with name 'app_users', while db.getCollectionNames returns all the collection names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) {
    if (collName.startsWith("app_users")) {
        print(collName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `filter` function to extract only the relevant collection names:

```
var cols = db.getCollectionNames().filter( function( col ) { 
  return col.startsWith( "app_users" ) 
} )
```

This code will populate the `cols` variable with an array of collection names that start with `app_users`.

Reference: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)